# Why has "in" been used in the sentence "he rose in his seat"?

Tags: prepositions

I found this definition for rise in LDOCE:

> 3 stand:   *formal*   to stand up:
>   Then she picked up her bag and rose to leave.
>
> rise from the table/your chair etc 
>   The chairman rose from his chair and came forward to greet her. 
>   He put down his glass and rose to his feet.

This suggests that "from" is the preposition of "rise." Then why "in" has been used?

> Hagrid helped Harry **on to** the train that would take him back to the
>   Dursleys, then handed him an envelope.
>   "Yer ticket fer Hogwarts, " he said. "First o' September -- King's Cross
>   -- it's all on yer ticket. Any problems with the Dursleys, send me a
>   letter with yer owl, she'll know where to find me.... See yeh soon,
>   Harry."
>   The train pulled out of the station. Harry wanted to watch Hagrid until
>   he was out of sight; **he rose in his seat** and pressed his nose against
>   the window, but he blinked and Hagrid had gone.

and one more question: Would it be wrong to use "onto" instead of "on to" in the bold sentence? What would the difference be in meaning and grammar?

Comment: You misunderstand the dictionary. The verb _rise_ does not **require** the preposition _from._ _Rise_ can take a number of prepositions, including _in, on, above, from, under, over,_ and _through_ (to name just a few). It is important to realize that examples in a dictionary are not "rules" or "requirements" that govern a given word's usage.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: So you accept that the meaning of "rise" here is "to stand up"?

Comment: No, the meaning here is not "to stand up". Visualize a seat in a train coach. With his feet on the floor in front of the seat, Harry raises his body, perhaps by pushing down with his arms on the armrests. This is what is conveyed by _he rose in his seat._ That is _not_ "to stand up". If the author had wanted to describe that action, she would have written _...he stood up and pressed his nose against the window._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because he didn't stand up: he didn't rise *from* (*out of*) his seat, he raised his body a little bit while still *in* his seat. He "moved from a lower position to a higher one" while still *in his seat*.

*rise*

> 1 Move from a lower position to a higher one

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rise))

To be *'in' his seat* means *to be 'enclosed' within* his seat; so one  can *rise in one's seat* by raising or boosting oneself up by several means. One's bottomside does not have to be in contact with the seat bottom to be considered *in one's seat*. Etiquette might say that, but grammar doesn't

---

I believe the difference between *onto/on to* and/or *into/in to* has been covered previously; search for it and if you can't find an answer, ask a new question.